# find-name-dired: find exited abnormally with code 2

Tags: find-file

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

I try to find all **el** files in emacs folder and all subfolders:

1. M-x find-name-dired
2. /path/to/emacs-25.1
3. *.el

Result is error:

```
  find . "(" -iname "*.el" ")" -exec ls -ld {} ";"
  File not found - "*.el"

  find exited abnormally with code 2 at Sat Sep 23 18:59:43
```

Answer (score 1):

This command depends on the `find` utility, which isn't present in Windows, at least in form Emacs expects it to be. You'd have to use Emacs in WSL or something like Cygwin to get this to work properly.

Comment: I have found [msys2](http://www.msys2.org) to be a life-saver on Windows.